# JAX-WS client to accept server certificates

Tags: java, mvc, swing, web-services, ssl

I am building a JAX-WS client with a GUI that connects to a server by accepting self-signed server certificates (when it uses HTTPS). The accepting of the certificates is not automatic, it is similar to what happens in any browser when you try to connect to a website that is not trusted. That is, usually a security pop-up appears displaying the certificate details and the user can either accept or reject the certificate.

Https Connection Endpoint function:

```
  private void buildControlEndpoint() {

    Map<String, Object> context = ((BindingProvider)control).getRequestContext();
    URL address = getConnectionEndpoint();
    if (address != null && Settings.getSettings().isUsingHttpConnection()) {
        context.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,address.toString());
    }
    else{
        address = getSecureConnectionEndpoint(); //returns example: https://19.18.88.131:5914
        SSLSocket socket;

        try {
            TrustManager[] trustCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    return;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    return;
                }
            } };
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) address.openConnection();
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(null, trustCerts, null);

            conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            SocketFactory factory = sc.getSocketFactory();
            socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(
                     getHostName(), getSecureConnectionEndpoint()
                    .getPort());

            socket.startHandshake();
            setCerts(socket.getSession().getPeerCertificates());

            X509Certificate[] peerCertificates = (X509Certificate[]) socket
                    .getSession().getPeerCertificates();
            X509Certificate serverCert = peerCertificates[0];
            System.out.println("Server Certificate is:   "+serverCert);
            CertificateController store = new CertificateController();

            String alias = getHostName() + "-" + getPort();

            if(store.CertificateComparer(alias, serverCert) == false){
                if(store.LoadCertificate(serverCert) == true){
                context.put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sc.getSocketFactory());
                store.WriteTrustStore(alias, serverCert);
                }
                else{
                    context.remove(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sc.getSocketFactory());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException | KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
        {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
        context.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,address.toString());

    }
}
```

Certificate Controller class:

```
public class CertificateController {

private X509Certificate c;
private KeyStore trustStore  = null;
private File keystoreFile = null;
char[] password = "changeit".toCharArray();

public void OpenCertificate(File file) throws Exception{
    InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
    c = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(targetStream);
}

public boolean CertificateComparer(String alias, X509Certificate c){
    try {
        OpenTrustStore();
        X509Certificate storecert = (X509Certificate) trustStore.getCertificate(alias);
        if(storecert == c){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public void WriteTrustStore(String alias, X509Certificate c){
    try {
        OpenTrustStore();
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, c);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(keystoreFile);
        trustStore.store(out, password);
        out.close();
    } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException
            | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean LoadCertificate(X509Certificate c){
    CertificatePopup PopUp = new CertificatePopup();
    if(PopUp.DisplayCertficate((X509Certificate) c) == true){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        PopUp.NeedCertificate();
        return false;
    }
}

private KeyStore OpenTrustStore() {
    char SEP = File.separatorChar;
    keystoreFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + SEP + "lib"
            + SEP + "security" + SEP + "cacerts");
    try {
        setTrustStore(trustStore);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
        trustStore.load(in, password);
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return trustStore;
}

public KeyStore getTrustStore() {
    return trustStore;
}
public void setTrustStore(KeyStore trustStore) {
    try {
        this.trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public X509Certificate getC() {
    return c;
}

public void setC(X509Certificate c) {
    this.c = c;
}
}
```

Pop-up view class:

```
public class CertificatePopup {

public boolean DisplayCertficate(java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert){
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    String message =  " Do you want to accept this certificate? \n"
            + "\n Certificate for: " + cert.getSubjectDN()
            + "\n Certificate issued by: "
            + cert.getIssuerDN()
            + "\n The certificate is valid from: "
            + cert.getNotBefore() + "\n Certificate SN#: "
            + cert.getSerialNumber() + "\n Generated with: "
            + cert.getSigAlgName();

    String title = "Security Alert";
    String[] options = { "yes", "no" };
    int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(panel, message, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[0]);

    if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        return true;
    } else if (confirm == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}

public void NeedCertificate(){
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "GUI needs a valid certificate to use HTTPS!","ERROR!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
}
```

And somewhere in the main class I am calling:

```
buildControlEndpoint();
```

This code works perfectly fine, although I have my doubts about a few things:

1. Obviously security is the most important thing here! Although I am accepting the certificates manually, how risky is this from Security provider point of view? I know I am liable to man in the middle attacks, but don't browsers follow a similar strategy? At end of the day the user is liable.
2. The code structure! I haven't done much of GUI programming before, so I am worried that my design pattern might be not so intelligent. Although I have tried to follow MVC, I not confident about it. I haven't used any `ActionListener`s because I know it is not necessary when you have just `JOptionPane`. Is there something I could do better in designing the code?
3. Just discovered a new bug, it occurs when I am trying to load certificates from multiple servers one after another.`JOptionPane` hangs as multiple windows open in quick succession. I tried encapsulating it in `EventQueue.invokeLater`, still doesn't help. Is there any known workaround for this?